# Is it possible to return first not null value for different Java types with Optionals?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

```
String myFunction(Optional<ClassWithIdAsString> instanceWithIdAsString, Optional<ClassWithIdAsLong> instanceWithIdAsLong) {

String resultId = instanceWithIdAsString.map(ClassWithIdAsString::getId)
                .map(id -> String.valueOf(id))
                .orElseGet(t -> instanceWithIdAsLong
                .map(ClassWithIdAsLong::getId));
return resultId;
}
```

Above code doesn't compile... I receive:

> Bad return type in method reference: can not convert java.lang.String
>   to U

During compilation:

> incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

By Long in above names I mean Long wrapper class.
I've made big research and didn't find anything similar but hope for some workaround. Making above id's the same type is not an option for me.

Comment: When you use `.map` the stream works on the map return value, so you're passing an entity to the map and mapping to `String` and then working with the String man

Comment: I think it's better return `Optional<String >` instead of `String` in `myFunction` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 String id = instanceWithIdAsString.map(ClassWithIdAsString::getId)
            .map(id -> String.valueOf(id))
            .orElseGet(() -> instanceWithIdAsLong
            .map(ClassWithIdAsLong::getId).orElse(""));
```

Does not ClassWithIdAsString::getId return a String as ID and ClassWithIdAsLong::getId a long as ID?

If yes, it has to be the other way round:

```
String id = instanceWithIdAsString.map(ClassWithIdAsLong::getId)
            .map(id -> String.valueOf(id))
            .orElseGet(() -> instanceWithIdAsLong
            .map(ClassWithIdAsString::getId).orElse(""));
```

In the case, that both instances are null it returns "".

I hope that is ok for you.

I hope that works.

Comment: Thanks! It works. As first answer with working code I will accept this.

Answer (score 2):

A few problems with your code:

1. You cannot use the identifier `id` as the variable to the `map` operation as it's already declared in the enclosing scope.
2. `orElseGet` takes a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), However you're doing `t -> ...` which does not satisfy the function descriptor of the `Supplier` functional interface.
3. The `map` operation in `orElseGet` is currently returning an `Optional<Long>` rather than a `String`.
4. Given the call to `map(ClassWithIdAsString::getId)` returns a `Optional<String>`, then it's redundant to call `String.valueOf` on the subsequent call of `.map(id -> String.valueOf(id))` (infact you don't need this operation at all) and is only working due to the overload `valueOf(Object obj)`.

All can be fixed with:

```
String id = instanceWithIdAsString
                .map(ClassWithIdAsString::getId)                 
                .orElseGet(() -> String.valueOf(instanceWithIdAsLong
                                       .map(ClassWithIdAsLong::getId)
                                       .orElse(-1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your last call to the map() on the optional inside of the orElse clause. Since it's an optional of string, orElse should return a string, but inside it you return an optional.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but after first answer with code now I see what you exactly meant.